# Is there a way to run a linear regression in python using counts of variables in your data set with date as the predictor?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I am trying to create a linear model to predict the amount of crime in a given year.

The Data set is set up as follows :-

Example:-

Each data point refers to a crime at that given date

```
Date      Crime
12-31-15   yes
12-15-15   yes
11-14-13   yes
03-15-11   yes
```

I want to run a linear regression with my predictor being the year, and the predicted variable being the amount of crime per year.

What I have done, is calculated the counts for the crimes for each year, giving me basically:

```
df['countsofarrests'] = df.groupby('year')['year'].transform('count')
```

`x (2011, 2012, 2013... 2018)` the years

`y (4123, 2312, 3231... 1231)` the amount of crime per year

My question is, can I do this in a way so that I can predict crime in 2019, and have to combine by year? Doing it this way, I feel like I am losing a lot of data.

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

regressor = LinearRegression()

model = regressor.fit(x, y)

model.predict(2019)
```

Comment: Hey, I have updated the code. What you want is super simple.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is this :) :

```
model.predict([[2019]])
```

```
import pandas as pd

Date;Crime
12-31-15;yes
12-15-15;yes
11-14-13;yes
03-15-11;yes


df = pd.read_clipboard(sep=';')
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df['year'] = df.Date.dt.year

print(df)

Date    Crime   year
0   2015-12-31  yes 2015
1   2015-12-15  yes 2015
2   2013-11-14  yes 2013
3   2011-03-15  yes 2011

df = (df.groupby('year').Crime.count()).reset_index()
df
year    Crime
0   2011    1
1   2013    1
2   2015    2

X = df['year'].values.reshape(-1,1)
y = df['Crime']


from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
regressor = LinearRegression()
model = regressor.fit(X, y)

model.predict([[2019]]) 

array([2.83333333])
```

Comment: My issue isn't running the regression, more that doing so in this way reduces the data points i have from thousands in my data set to just the amount of years, which seems to me severely limits the regression. Am I over thinking this?

Comment: Oh, ok. just reduce the data to the year level, then predict the future. You still take advantage of linear regression. What years do you have in the data?